# Displaying some images seems to break styling on Google

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to display some photos on a page, and it is breaking the styling of the page.  Here is an example.  See on the right side of the page, the images are broken, and they actually get displayed over other HTML elements like an H2 tag which says "coming soon"

Example here:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=15

Any idea how to fix this?  The problem is worse on Google Chrome

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comehike.com%2Foutdoors%2Fparks%2Fpark.php%3Fpark_id%3D15&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html markup is a bit confusing, for one they all use http://wwww reference but they are hosted on the same server.  Maybe I missed  something but you can probably use a local site path relative to the web page, something that would be simplified sort of like the following *non working code example*:

```
<span style="margin: 3px;">
<a href="hikes/hike_image.php hike_photo_id=&amp;photo_path=img/hiking_photos/108_2/full_cannon2.jpg">
<img src="img/hiking_photos/108_2/small_cannon2.jpg" 
style="border: none;"></a>
</span>
```

This would make for a faster load time, save bandwith, and just be plain more efficient in my very humble opinion. Usually one uses http:// in image links when they are on a remote site.

There are multiple broken images when I load the page, it seems maybe it is the script that generates the markup that is breaking the layout.

To fix this, I would rip out the whole image-generation thing and simplify the mark-up just to have it work 'statically', ie without scripts to output images and/or markup.

Then, once it works in a static manner I would attack dynamic output, though I rarely use such techniques because I feel most of the time they are overkill for the small projects I maintain.

Happy coding & good day friend.

**Update:**

**Storing the image path in a variable for easy site-wide changes:**

One (simple) option is to use good old php for your image paths. IE, in main script:

```
 define('BASE_PATH',realpath('.'));
 define('IMG_PATH', BASE_PATH . "/img/);
// to inlude an image::
 <img src="<php echo IMG_PATH; ?> pic.jpg" />
```

This way, changing IMG_PATH would change all the img tags that use the variable, and by using BASE_PATH this would work even if you move or copy the site on a different host.

Look up basename() function the man and related functions for more tips and examples like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Could you please explain how shortening the urls would save load time and bandwidth?  I am very curious about that point of yours.

Comment: For every image you load, you make an actual http request that apache has to process. At the minimum, you have the overhead of DNS resolution to load the image. Depending on your server and dns/routing configuration, if the DNS resolution is done locally on your server through hostfile for example, then you will not use more bandwith, but if your machine does not resolve the hostname, it has to call on your service provider for the resolution of the domain name  and the image will come from that route instead of a local fetch. Hope I was clear, this is hard to explain with my bad english!

Comment: Thank you - that was helpful.  But in case the site grows, and I need a second server, would I have to put back all the paths which start like this /directory/ to the full http://www.. call?

Comment: Updated the answer to reply on your comment.